# how to check if there is any string from index 0 to 5 in an array of type Any

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of type any in which i am appending string data. now how do i check that the array i.e final list contains alphabets from index position 0 to 5

Comment: Can you show your attempt and maybe an example as well?

Comment: you can check with `print(array.startIndex)` array being your final list

Comment: @chirag90 i have print it now what

Comment: @nishant.narola, you need to update your question and also provide what you have tried. As i thought you only wanted to see start index of your array.

Comment: how do i check for index range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first slice your `array with a range`. Then `filter` the sliced array by checking if the elements can be `type cast to string`. If the count of filtered array is equal to your range then you can say first n elements are of type `String`.

This is test code I have tried:

```
let testArray: [Any] = ["a", 2, 3,"S", 4, 2, 5, 1.0, "a"]

let slicedArrayCount = Array(testArray[0..<5]).filter { (object) -> Bool in
    if let _ = object as? String {
        return true
    }
    return false
}.count
```

Comment: `if arr.prefix(6).first(where: { $0 is String }) != nil {
    print("there is a String")
}`